# Async tasks execution with dependency

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, nsoperationqueue

**Situation:**

I have 2 tasks says **T1** & **T2** in async background mode. **T2** depends on **T1** and have **successBlock** which is executes after the completion of the both tasks **T1** & **T2**.

Quick diagram is below for better understanding.

> [image]

**Edit:**

To better understanding the tasks, you can assume T1 and T2 are the API calls which always be going to execute in async mode. I need some output data from T1 to hit T2 API. After the completion of the both tasks I need to update UI.

---

To accomplish this scenario, I have added my first async work in **T1** and second work in **T2** and dependency of **T2** to **T1** and successblock have dependency on both tasks.

**Code Work**

1. My Tasks

   ```
   class TaskManager {

       static let shared = TaskManager()

       func task1Call(complete: @escaping ()->()) {
           DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
               for i in 0...10 {
                   print("~~> Task 1 Executing ..", i)
                   sleep(1)
               }
               complete()
           }
       }

       func task2Call(complete: @escaping ()->()) {
           DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
               for i in 0...10 {
                   print("==> Task 2 Executing ..", i)
                   sleep(1)
               }
               complete()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Execute Tasks

   ```
   class Execution {

       // Managing tasks with OperationQueue
       func executeTaskWithOperation()  {

           let t1 = BlockOperation {
               TaskManager.shared.task1Call {
                   print("Task 1 Completed")
               }
           }

           let t2 = BlockOperation {
               TaskManager.shared.task2Call {
                   print("Task 2 Completed")
               }
           }

           let successBlock = BlockOperation {
               print("Tasks Completed")
           }

           let oper = OperationQueue()

           t2.addDependency(t1)
           successBlock.addDependency(t2)
           successBlock.addDependency(t1)

           oper.addOperations([t1, t2, successBlock], waitUntilFinished: true)

       }
   }

   let e = Execution()
   e.executeTaskWithOperation()
   ```

---

**Issue:**

Both tasks are executing parallelly and **successBlock** executes before the completion of task 1 and task 2.

**Console Output:**

```
==> Task 2 Executing .. 0
Tasks Completed
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 0
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 1
==> Task 2 Executing .. 1
==> Task 2 Executing .. 2
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 2
==> Task 2 Executing .. 3
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 3
==> Task 2 Executing .. 4
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 4
==> Task 2 Executing .. 5
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 5
==> Task 2 Executing .. 6
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 6
==> Task 2 Executing .. 7
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 7
==> Task 2 Executing .. 8
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 8
==> Task 2 Executing .. 9
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 9
~~> Task 1 Executing .. 10
==> Task 2 Executing .. 10
Task 1 Completed
Task 2 Completed
```

I unable to figure out what wrong I am doing, even same code work fines when I use sync mode instead of async.

Comment: so you want it in a serial manner, why not use a dispatchGroup call instead? in your queue I didn't see any suspension on the running queue which doesn't prevent NSOperation to get the next process once the current one goes to a diff thread

Comment: @Joshua , Sorry I didn't understand **in your queue I didn't see any suspension on the running queue which doesn't prevent NSOperation to get the next process once the current one goes to a diff thread**

Comment: oh, what I mean is that it didn't prevent NSOperation to perform the next process in your example [t1, t2] t1 executes and goes to background the moment it goes to background there's nothing informing NSOperation to wait for it to complete before proceeding to the next process (t2). Sync prevents that from happening by blocking the current thread until it finishes. if you want more control I suggest using a GroupDispatchQueue or even a DispatchSemaphore

Comment: @Joshua Thanks buddy, it worked and I added conclude answer. If in case, you need to add any more points to my answer then please add it.

Comment: glad I managed to give you an idea. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [Joshua's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246872/async-tasks-execution-with-dependency?noredirect=1#comment104724422_59246872) , I able to conclude the answer.

---

Execution changed from **`OperationQueue`** to  **`DispatchGroup`** and **`DispatchSemaphore`**.

**DispatchGroup :** It makes sure both task tasks are done and then it calls `notify` block.

**DispatchSemaphore :** It holds the async resource with **wait** command until we wont send the **signal** command i.e. we are saying to semaphore to hold yourself until the task1 is not completed.

Sample code of tasks.

```
class Execution {
    // Managing tasks with DispatchGroup

    func executeTaskWithGroup() {
        let groups = DispatchGroup()
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)
        groups.enter()
        semaphore.wait()
        TaskManager.shared.task1Call {
            groups.leave()
            semaphore.signal()
        }

        groups.enter()
        TaskManager.shared.task2Call {
            groups.leave()
        }

        groups.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
            print("Tasks Completed")
        }

    }

}
```

---

To execute command all we need to do is.

```
let e = Execution()
e.executeTaskWithGroup()
```

But above code is executed in the main thread and block the UI. To prevent this you need to call above piece of code in background queue like below.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "MyQueue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)

queue.async {
    let e = Execution()
    e.executeTaskWithGroup()
}
```

Now everything works fine as per my needed.

---

**AddOn**

In case, if someone requirement is to call multiple API along with the above scenario then add your tasks in async in the queue.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "MyQueue", qos: .background, attributes: .concurrent, autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)

queue.async {
    let e1 = Execution()
    e1.executeTaskWithGroup()
}

queue.async {
    let e2 = Execution()
    e2.executeTaskWithGroup()
}
```

Now both **e1** and **e2** executes parallelly without blocking main thread.

---

**References :**

- [Using Dispatch Group & Semaphore to Group iOS Async Tasks](https://medium.com/@alfianlosari/using-dispatch-group-semaphore-to-group-ios-async-tasks-alfian-losari-81335fa6e92e)
- [A Quick Look at Semaphores in Swift](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/a-quick-look-at-semaphores-6b7b85233ddb)

Answer (score 0):

Your `t1` and `t2` are block operations that spawn background threads (which each do some printing and then exit, but it doesn't matter).  Once they finish spawning, they're considered completed.  `successBlock` depends on the two background threads being spawned, and then it's done.  You want the work in the `BlockOperation` itself:

```swift
class Execution {

    // Managing tasks with OperationQueue
    func executeTaskWithOperation()  {

      let t1 = BlockOperation {
          for i in 0...10 {
              print("~~> Task 1 Executing ..", i)
              sleep(1)
          }
          print("Task 1 completed")
        }

        let t2 = BlockOperation {
          for i in 0...10 {
            print("==> Task 2 Executing ..", i)
            sleep(1)
          }
         print("Task 2 Completed")
        }

        let successBlock = BlockOperation {
            print("Tasks Completed")
        }

        let oper = OperationQueue()

        t2.addDependency(t1)  // Remove this to see concurrent exec of t1 and t2
        successBlock.addDependency(t2)
        successBlock.addDependency(t1)

        oper.addOperations([t1, t2, successBlock], waitUntilFinished: true)

    }
}

let e = Execution()
e.executeTaskWithOperation()
```

Edit: For execution on a background thread, override `Operation`.

```swift
class AsyncOp: Operation {
  let task: String
  var running = false
  var done = false

  init(_ task: String) {
    self.task = task
  }

  override var isAsynchronous: Bool { true }
  override var isExecuting: Bool {
    get { running }
    set {
      willChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
      running = newValue
      didChangeValue(forKey: "isExecuting")
    }
  }
  override var isFinished: Bool {
    get { done }
    set {
      willChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
      done = newValue
      didChangeValue(forKey: "isFinished")
    }
  }

  override func main() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      self.isExecuting = true
      for i in 0...10 {
        print("\(self.task) Executing ..", i)
        sleep(1)
      }
      print("Done")
      self.isExecuting = false
      self.isFinished = true
    }
  }

  override func start() {
    print("\(task) starting")
    main()
  }
}

class Execution {
  // Managing tasks with OperationQueue
  func executeTaskWithOperation()  {
    let t1 = AsyncOp("task1")
    let t2 = AsyncOp("task2")
    let successBlock = BlockOperation {
      print("Tasks Completed")
    }

    let oper = OperationQueue()
    t2.addDependency(t1)
    successBlock.addDependency(t2)
    successBlock.addDependency(t1)
    oper.addOperations([t1, t2, successBlock], waitUntilFinished: true)
  }
}

let e = Execution()
e.executeTaskWithOperation()
```

Comment: Bro I already mentioned this point in the last line of question, check **... even same code work fines when I use sync mode instead of async.**

Comment: Remove the dependency and they will execute in parallel.  The point is that spawning background threads makes t1 and t2 consider themselves done.  All your original code is doing is making sure that the thread spawning happens in a particular order, and that the background threads spawn before the successBlock completes.

Comment: Let me re-phase **I want to execute my tasks in background thread, T2 needs to be executed after T1 and success block needs to be called after the completion of T1 & T2**. In your case, I have to execute code parallelly and in the background thread, which is not in my requirement.

Comment: Then you want to override Operation and use isAsynchronous, not use BlockOperation.  Give me a few minutes and I'll see if I can put something together to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

[Dexecutor](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core/wiki/How-Do-I-%3F) for the rescue here

Disclaimer: I am the owner of Dexecutor

Dexecutor can be used easily for [workflow](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-examples#2-workflow-example) like use case

[image]

Here is [sample Application](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dexecutor/flow/WorkFlowApplication.java)